# How to get a single rainbow coloured legend for a group of rainbow coloured curves all having same line style?

Tags: plotting, legending, style

A test code to clarify the requirement:

```
{k1, k2, dk} = {0.01, 0.09, 0.01};

f1[x_] = Sin[k x];
f2[x_] = Cos[k x];
f3[x_] = Sin[k x]*Cos[k x];

Plot[Evaluate[Table[Style[
{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]},ColorData["Rainbow"][(k - k1)/(k2 - k1)]],
{k, k1, k2, dk}]],{x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi},
PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[0.03, 0.01], Dashing[0.004]},
PlotLegends -> {Placed[{"Amp1", "Amp2", "Amp3"}, {Right, Bottom}]}]
```

[image]

Now, the problem is in the **monotone** color of legends. I need **Rainbow** color legends for all the line styles (here three).

As an example of a **Rainbow** coloured line legend for a thick line style appears as:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "rainbow color legends"? What exactly should they look like?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: The black line on white paper is very beautiful and conveys more information than color. Even with a rainbow-colored line legend, how is the reader going to precisely translate color into numerical value?

Answer (score 11):

```
sparkline = Plot[0, {x, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#] &), 
  PlotTheme -> "Sparkline", Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
legend = LineLegend[Dashing /@ {None, {Medium, Small}, Small}, 
  {"Amp1", "Amp2", "Amp3"}, 
  "LegendItem" -> {sparkline}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Style[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][(k - k1)/(k2 - k1)]], {k, k1, k2, dk}]], 
 {x, -5  Pi, 5  Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[0.03, 0.01], Dashing[0.004]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[legend, {Right, Bottom}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is "LegendItem" in red after excecuting the code? It seems it is not an option of LineLegend but still works. @kglr

Comment: You can use `Method -> "LegendItem" -> {sparkline}` instead of `"LegendItem" -> {sparkline}` to avoid red highlighting of `"LegendItem"`.

Comment: @kglr Is there any other way to do it...without using "LegendItem". Since it is fragile command, in the sense that it changes the formatting style of all labels & legends text.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure that there is a way to use the built-in legends and achieve your desired result. However, you can build `Line` objects with the desired properties, and then insert them in your plot manually (e.g. with [`Overlay`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html)):

```
lines = Map[
  Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], #,
     Line[
       Table[{x, 0}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}],
       VertexColors -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1]
     ]
    },
    ImageSize -> Small, PlotRange -> {All, {-0.01, 0.01}}
  ] &,
  {Dashing[{}], Dashing[{0.1, 0.05}], Dashing[{0.03, 0.07}]}
];

Column[lines]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. For an article having multiple such plots, it will require to much manual adjustment and matching of line styles to meet the standards of research journals.

Comment: @KumarGauravSagar As a workaround, I would recommend making the lines in the legend plain black, and distinguishing them only by the dashing. That should already be understandable to your readers.